# Transformer Output waveform

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, transformer, magnetics, electric-machine

If input to a transformer is square/triangular, draw its output voltage waveform.

This problem was asked in one of my recent interviews, please help me with this problem.

Comment: If it is an ideal transformer, then the output is square triangular. If it is a real transformer, kindly provide some information about it, such as its intended use (power or signal) core material (stamped silicon steel or ferrite powder or what).

Comment: it was asked in interview. They didn'i mention anything.

Comment: For what position was the interview?

Comment: Transformer does not pass DC. Transformer has a finite bandwidth. The net effect of this is that any DC offset of the input signal will be lost, and the AC output may be a filtered version of the input. This means that sharp edges of the input waveform will be more rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any wave like square/triangular wave is a summation of infinite no. of sine waves (fourier series).

For a linear device, the output response to a square wave input is *equivalent* to the summation of the respective responses for each of its sine component. Transformer induces sinusoidal voltage at the secondary for each of this sinusoidal input, and its summation defines the resulting output waveform. It will be square wave itself. The same shape and frequency as that of the input waveform is obtained at the output.

An ideal transformer can be considered as a linear device as --> \$V_o = V_i\frac{N2}{N1}\$

Hence the output would be square/triangular for square/triangular input.

Comment: So are you saying square wave in = square wave out?

Comment: Yea ideally....

Comment: @mkeith has already commented on what happens with a real transformer, which has a finite bandwidth. Ideal one has infinite bandwidth.